# attempt to index a number value

Tags: lua

```
GetSPLListResponse = "030200"

-- Playlists container
playlistsUUID = {}
playlistname = {}

-- TCP connection to the server
address = Properties["IP_Address"].Value
port = 11730
sock = TcpSocket.New()
sock.ReadTimeout = 0
sock.WriteTimeout = 0
sock.ReconnectTimeout = 5

sock.EventHandler = function(sock, evt, err)
    if evt == TcpSocket.Events.Connected then
        print("Server connected")
    elseif evt == TcpSocket.Events.Reconnect then
        print("Server reconnecting...")
    elseif evt == TcpSocket.Events.Data then
        print("Server has data")
        print("Socket buffer lenght: " .. sock.BufferLength)
        buflen = sock.BufferLength
        message = sock:Read(buflen)
        messagestring =      -- convert HEX message to String
              message:gsub(
              '.',
              function(c)
                return string.format('%02X', string.byte(c))
              end                  
              )
              print("Message after HEX to String " .. messagestring)
        
        if string.find(messagestring, GetSPLListResponse) then -- GET SPL UUID LIST
            print("GetSPLList Response received")
            playlistsUUID = math.floor((#message - 16) / 16) -- calculating the amount of playlists
            print("Playlists calculated: " .. playlistsUUID)
            
            for i = 1, playlistsUUID do -- putting each playlist data in a array
                playlistsUUID[i] = string.sub(messagestring, i * 16, i * 16 + 16) --chops the data into 16byte pieces into the array
            end
            Controls.PlaylistBox.Choices = playlistsUUID
```

I'm trying to create an array with UUID of each playlist available on a remote server, but I obtain a **attempt to index a number value (global 'playlistsUUID')** error at **playlistsUUID[i] = string.sub(messagestring, i * 16, i * 16 + 16)**

a typical **messagestring** after HEX to String conversion is: `060E2B340205010A0E100101010302008300002D000000010000000200000010AD17FC696B49454DB17D593DB3E553E59BF5455689ED4C019731C6DD3C071F0E00`

Comment: Your code is strange because you use the variable `playlistsUUID` to store the playlist table (the result you want, initialized with `{}`) and you also use the same variable `playlistsUUID` as a counter (`playlistsUUID = math.floor`). You might need an additional variable `PlaylistCount`.

Comment: I'm really sorry Piglet to bother you and other advanced users: I've tried to solve the problem by myself and I've read all other similar questions here and some more pages (and Lua guide). Unfortunately this is my first attempt with lua (and I've just a little pyhton experience...), and I'm still not aware even of things that you consider obvious... Moreover, the heart of the code was written by one of the developers who works for the company that produces the system in which it will be used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an additional variable `PlaylistCount` to make it work.

If you overwrite the variable `playlistsUUID` with `math.floor`, then `playlistsUUID` is a number. Later, when you write `playlistsUUID[i]` you are trying to reference a table but the type of `playlistsUUID` is `number`. So you get an execution error from Lua because the type is incorrect.

```
GetSPLListResponse = "030200"

-- Playlists container
playlistsUUID = {}
playlistname = {}

-- TCP connection to the server
address = Properties["IP_Address"].Value
port = 11730
sock = TcpSocket.New()
sock.ReadTimeout = 0
sock.WriteTimeout = 0
sock.ReconnectTimeout = 5

sock.EventHandler = function(sock, evt, err)
    if evt == TcpSocket.Events.Connected then
        print("Server connected")
    elseif evt == TcpSocket.Events.Reconnect then
        print("Server reconnecting...")
    elseif evt == TcpSocket.Events.Data then
        print("Server has data")
        print("Socket buffer lenght: " .. sock.BufferLength)
        buflen = sock.BufferLength
        message = sock:Read(buflen)
        messagestring =      -- convert HEX message to String
              message:gsub(
              '.',
              function(c)
                return string.format('%02X', string.byte(c))
              end                  
              )
              print("Message after HEX to String " .. messagestring)
        
        if string.find(messagestring, GetSPLListResponse) then -- GET SPL UUID LIST
            print("GetSPLList Response received")
            PlaylistCount = math.floor((#message - 16) / 16) -- calculating the amount of playlists
            print("Playlists calculated: " .. PlaylistCount)
            
            for i = 1, PlaylistCount do -- putting each playlist data in a array
                playlistsUUID[i] = string.sub(messagestring, i * 16, i * 16 + 16) --chops the data into 16byte pieces into the array
            end
            Controls.PlaylistBox.Choices = playlistsUUID
```